# Change button value using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to change submit button value on contact form using JavaScript, but it didn't work. The submit button value won't change.

Here is the HTML:

```js
$("#contactForm").submit(function(event) {
  /* stop form from submitting normally */
  event.preventDefault();

  /* get some values from elements on the page: */
  var $form = $(this),
    $submit = $form.find('button[type="submit"]'),
    name_value = $form.find('input[name="name"]').val(),
    dropdown_value = $form.find('textarea[name="dropdown"]').val(),
    email_value = $form.find('input[name="email"]').val(),
    telephone_value = $form.find('textarea[name="telephone"]').val(),
    message_value = $form.find('textarea[name="message"]').val(),
    url = $form.attr('action');

  /* Send the data using post */
  var posting = $.post(url, {
    name: name_value,
    dropdown: dropdown_value,
    email: email_value,
    telephone: telephone_value,
    message: message_value
  });

  posting.done(function(data) {
    /* Put the results in a div */
    $("#contactResponse").html(data);

    /* Change the button text. */
    document.getElementById("submit").value = "Thank You";


    /* Disable the button. */
    $submit.attr("disabled", true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="name" class="dream-search" placeholder="your name"> <span>and I want to</span>
<select name="dropdown" class="verb-dropdown">
  <option value="" disabled selected>opta</option>
  <option value="b">optb</option>
  <option value="c">optc</option>
  <option value="d">optd</option>
  <option value="e">opte</option>
  <option value="others">others</option>
</select>.</p><br>
<p><span>Please contact me</span> <input type="text" name="email" class="dream-search" placeholder="your email"><span>and</span>
  <input type="text" name="telephone" class="dream-search" placeholder="your phone"><br>
  <textarea name="message" placeholder="..."></textarea><br>
  <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="button round"></a>
  <div id="contactResponse"></div>
```

Update:

```js
$("#contactForm").submit(function(event) {
  /* stop form from submitting normally */
  event.preventDefault();

  /* get some values from elements on the page: */
  var $form = $(this),
    $submit = $form.find('input[type="submit"]'),
    name_value = $form.find('input[name="name"]').val(),
    dropdown_value = $form.find('textarea[name="dropdown"]').val(),
    email_value = $form.find('input[name="email"]').val(),
    telephone_value = $form.find('textarea[name="telephone"]').val(),
    message_value = $form.find('textarea[name="message"]').val(),
    url = $form.attr('action');

  /* Send the data using post */
  var posting = $.post(url, {
    name: name_value,
    dropdown: dropdown_value,
    email: email_value,
    telephone: telephone_value,
    message: message_value
  });

  posting.done(function(data) {
    /* Change the button text. */
    $($submit).attr("value", "Thank you");


    /* Disable the button. */
    $submit.attr("disabled", true);
  });
});
```

Comment: can you include jsfiddle sampleof your code or any other online editor link.

Comment: you are messing up with use of jquery and simple javascript.....to change simply your button text assign it some it say `btnsubmit` and then use use `$('#btnsubmit').val('Thank you');`

Answer (score 0):

Check line

```
$submit = $form.find( 'button[type="submit"]' ),
```

You do not have `<button>`, you have `<input type="submit">`. Try changing that line to this:

```
$submit = $form.find( 'input[type="submit"]' ),
```

Live demo with my change:

```js
$("#contactForm").submit(function(event) {
  /* stop form from submitting normally */
  event.preventDefault();

  /* get some values from elements on the page: */
  var $form = $(this),
    $submit_old = $form.find('button[type="submit"]');
  $submit_new = $form.find('input[type="submit"]');
  console.log($($submit_old).attr("value")); //lundefined
  console.log($($submit_new).attr("value")); //log value "Send"

  /* change value */
  $($submit_new).attr("value", "New value!");
  console.log($($submit_new).attr("value")); //log value "New value!"
  /* Send the data using post */
  return false //only for demo, add here your code

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="contactForm">

  <input type="text" name="name" class="dream-search" placeholder="your name"> <span>and I want to</span>
  <select name="dropdown" class="verb-dropdown">
    <option value="" disabled selected>opta</option>
    <option value="b">optb</option>
    <option value="c">optc</option>
    <option value="d">optd</option>
    <option value="e">opte</option>
    <option value="others">others</option>
  </select>.</p><br>
  <p><span>Please contact me</span> <input type="text" name="email" class="dream-search" placeholder="your email"><span>and</span>
    <input type="text" name="telephone" class="dream-search" placeholder="your phone"><br>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="..."></textarea><br>
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="button round"></a>
    <div id="contactResponse"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: not working but thanks for your answer you points out the wrong code

Comment: @Reza You missed `<form>` tag. Check my update with demo. I used your `button[type=submit` and my `input[type=submit]`.

Comment: I update my code above based on your code. I think in my code "posting.done(function(data)" didn't work properly? what do you think? because I want the POST function is 'done' first before change the value. otherwise it should be an error right?

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("submit").value="New text";
```

Comment: Check Thomas Ferro answer your html is missing the form tag.

After you have the form tag in order to use only javascript you can set it like this:
    document.getElementById("yourForm").addEventListener("submit", myFunction);
function myFunction() {
  
    /* all the stuff you need */
  
    /* Change the button text. */
    document.getElementById("submit").value="Thank You";
}

Answer (score 0):

With `jquery` you can use `.val('YourValue')` to change the value of elements.

In your case:
    `$('input#submit').val('Thank You');`

Comment: I've updated my code above also based on @Dave answer. it didn't work. any suggestion? many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you didn't have an actual **form** tag.

```
<form id="contactForm">
```

Also, be sure to wait for the DOM to be ready before you add any event. You can do that by using the **ready** function on your main DOM element.

```
$(document).ready(function() { [...] });
```

Here's a fiddle with the solution to you main problem : https://jsfiddle.net/hamz2v77/

Answer (score 0):

you can use the  bellow options

```
$('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
$("#submit").text("Thank you"); //update button value
```